# cant able to print first 20 even and odd numbers in assemble language

Tags: assembly

I am using procedures for printing even and odd numbers but it is not working 
what is wrong with my code? since I am new to assembly language

This is my main funtion:

```
.data
S BYTE ?
.code
main proc
call ven
MOV AH,4ch
INT 21h
main endp
```

this is my procedure:

```
ven proc
MOV S,0  \\ S is a variable
L1:
JE ter
MOV AX,S
MOV bl,2
DIV bl
CMP AH,0
JE EVE
JNE ODD
EVE:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,AL
INT 21h
jmp L1
ODD:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,AL
INT 21h
jmp L1
ter:
RET
ven ENDP
END MAIN
```

is there is something with my `ven` procedure aur I am linking it with main with a wrong manner.

Comment: invalid instruction operand at MOV AX,S ..

Comment: There's some problem or lack of understanding on almost every line (or every other). Which is actually normal for somebody new to Assembly. Plus irritating MASM quirk syntax. What do you use to learn Assembly? (I would like to check it to see how this can happen)

Answer (score 1):

there are some little errors in you code, I fixed them and pointed them with arrows (`◄■■■`) :

```
.stack 100h       ;◄■■■ PROCEDURES REQUIERE STACK.
.data
S dw ?            ;◄■■■ DW, NOT BYTE, BECAUSE AX IS TYPE DW.
.code
main proc
call ven
;call outdec
MOV AH,4ch
INT 21h
main endp

ven proc
MOV S,0
L1:
INC S             ;◄■■■ S+1
CMP S,20          ;◄■■■ IF S > 20...
JA ter            ;◄■■■ ...JUMP TO TER.
MOV AX,S
MOV bl,2
DIV bl
CMP AH,0
JE EVE
JNE ODD
EVE:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,AL         ;◄■■■ HERE YOU PRINT "AL", BUT THE NUMBER
INT 21h           ;◄■■■ TO PRINT IS "S". USE "CALL OUTDEC".
jmp L1
ODD:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,AL         ;◄■■■ HERE YOU PRINT "AL", BUT THE NUMBER
INT 21h           ;◄■■■ TO PRINT IS "S". USE "CALL OUTDEC".
jmp L1
ter:
RET
ven ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: giving me output like 512 513 514 517 but not printing even or odd numbers